# How do I run a shell script from puppet?

Tags: puppet, node.js

I need to install `npm` which is done by `curl http://npmjs.org/install.sh | sh` and being new to using `puppet`, I am a bit confused on how this should be done.

I am well aware of creating a `package {}` entry that invokes an `exec` target, but as I install `npm` from source, this isn't going to cut it.

I clearly don't want to build `npm` every time my `puppet` makes a pull, so I need someway to check if it is installed or not as well, so just making an `exec {}` alone isn't enough either.

What can I do?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Something like

```
exec { "install npm":
    command => "/usr/bin/curl http://npmjs.org/install.sh | sh",
    creates => "/some/directory/somewhere"
}
```

Should do the trick.

However, I would *strongly* advise against doing this, as it makes your installation process dependent on so many other things working correctly, and drops untracked files who-knows-where in your filesystem (and that's even before we start talking about the security implications of running untrusted and unverifiable code automatically).  You'd be far better off making a native package for your OS, placing it in a local repo, and installing that using a package resource.

Answer (score 4):

I would "second" everything Womble said about packaging it and installing it via package management tools from a local repository.  Depending on the platform, there might also be dependable third-party repositories that you could use.

One minor nitpick regarding Womble's answer: the [puppet style guide](http://docs.puppetlabs.com/guides/style_guide.html) recommends using single quotes unless you need double quotes for variable interpolation.  In the code that Womble shows, there are no variables, so all the " should instead be '.

Note that a lot of the puppet documentation hasn't been updated to reflect this recommendation, so you'll see double quotes in plenty of places even in the official docs.  The style guide and [puppet-lint](https://github.com/rodjek/puppet-lint) both reflect current recommended best-practices, and the docs will hopefully eventually be fixed.